# Response of REST API with the logs generated during execution of the Request

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger

I am writing some REST apis with `swagger-ui` . Now during the execution process of this apis I am performing some operation, Which I need to send as a response of the API. Consider the following response as an example:

```
{
  "Database": [
    "Table 1 created",
    "data 1 inserted",
    "Data 3 insertion failed"
  ],
   "Kafka": [
    "Topic 1 created",
    "Topic 3 deleted",
    "Topic 4  rebalanced"
  ]
}
```

So is there any framework for this, or I need to manually create the JSON object and send it as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using Spring MVC?

First: create a class for api response.

```
public class Data {
  private List<String> database = new ArrayList();
  private List<String> kafka = new ArrayList();

  public List<String> getDatabase() {
    return database;
  }

  public void setDatabase(List<String> database) {
    this.database = database;
  }

  public List<String> getKafka() {
    return kafka;
  }

  public void setKafka(List<String> kafka) {
    this.kafka = kafka;
  }
}
```

Second: use @ResponseBody annotation against the controller's method. This will make spring understand that method return value should be bound to the web response body.

```
@ResponseBody
public Data apiMethod() {
  return new Data();
}
```